# Same scancodes - how to differ?

Tags: mouse

I have the razer naga 2014 and I am having a problem with the wheel.
It has the four way wheel so I can go right/left/up/down. The problem is that

1. going left will do this (`evtest`)

   ```
   Event: time 1443121919.955225, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
   Event: time 1443121920.006229, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value -1
   ```
2. down

   ```
   Event: time 1443122067.933357, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
   Event: time 1443122068.063357, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value -1
   ```
3. right

   ```
   Event: time 1443122133.474197, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
   Event: time 1443122133.526168, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 1
   ```
4. up

   ```
   Event: time 1443122158.886481, -------------- EV_SYN ------------
   Event: time 1443122158.901480, type 2 (EV_REL), code 8 (REL_WHEEL), value 1
   ```

as you can see I am not able to differ going left and down / right and up to bind it to another action because it has the same codes. Is there a way to distinguish them?